# toggle show/hide of list items using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```js
var myApp = angular
  .module("myApp", [])
  .controller("listController", function($scope) {
   var foodList = [
     { name : 'Hyderbadi Koma',
       types : [
     { name : "sweet" },
     { name : "extra chatpata" },
    { name : "chatpata" }
   ],
    flag: 0
  }]; ...
    $scope.showhide = function(foodLists) {
      if (foodLists.flag == 0)
        foodLists.flag++;
      else
        foodLists.flag--;
    };

  });
```

```html
...
        <td class="leftSection">
          <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="foodItem in foodList" ng-click="showhide(foodItem)" class="clic">
              {{ foodItem.name }}
              <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="foodType in foodItem.types" ng-hide="{{ foodItem.flag | filtering }}" class="unclic">
                  {{ foodType.name }} ///For watching variable flag {{foodItem.flag}}
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
     ...
```

**Now here after tracing i found that "ng-click" is performing its action of changing the flag value from 1 to 0 and vice versa. Though I am not able to debug why ng-hide is not performing its action simultaneously, please help!**

Comment: You are sending the `fooditem.flag` through a pipe, what is that pipe doing?

Comment: in ng-hide pipe there is used for filtering, there it is converting 0 to false and 1 to true.

Comment: that is working fine, just ng-click is doing nothing.

Comment: Are you passing ng-repeat the $index?

Comment: can you verify that the `showhide function` is existing on the correct scope?  (Maybe with scope inspector dev tool?)  Can you verify that `showhide function` might be getting called with a simple `console.log('showhide called', foodLists);` as its first line?  What about if you make a `<button ng-click="showhide(foodItem)">Test</button>` as child of the `<li>` instead of `ng-click` on the `<li>`?   Beyond that, if you can isolate the problem in a plunker, that would be much easier for us to help debug.

Comment: which is line 28 and col 5 ?? expose the lines that cause error and the json data that your passing in the ng-repeat

Comment: ng-click is working..i traced it, it is changing the value (0(false) and 1(true)). But now it seems after the value changes, ng-hide does not perform its function.i.e. doesnt hide the child list items when value flag becomes 0(false).

Answer (score -1):

try this...

```
<td>
      <ul ng-repeat="foodItem in foodList">
        <li class="clic">
          <a href="#" ng-click="showhide(foodItem)"> {{ foodItem.name }}</a>

            <ul ng-repeat="foodType in foodItem.types">
              <li  ng-hide="{{ foodItem.flag}}" class="unclic">
                {{ foodType.name }}
              </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </td>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/sTWHI3SQeKgNN7QoOrrw

Comment: What exactly you want? Initially you said ng-click is not performing it's action. The above code is for ng-click event. If ng-hide is not working, I suspect something wrong with "filtering". Could you provide additional code like how "filter" is injecting, etc. It will be nice to see the code in plunker editor.

Comment: i want to create nested unordered list where clicking the parent item will show and hide the respective child.

Comment: The problem here is curly braces: ng-hide='{{ foodItem.flag | sh }}'. Just remove the curly braces. 'ng-hide' is a directive and shouldn't use curly brace binding.  https://plnkr.co/edit/sTWHI3SQeKgNN7QoOrrw?p=preview